# REACT - Error: Attempted import error/ App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Returns an error: ./src/index.js
Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App').

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const  increment = () => {
        setCount(count + 1);
    };

    return (
      <div>
          <h2> counter app </h2>
          <button onClick={increment}>Clicked {count} times</button>
      </div>
    );
};
```

**index**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 14):

In Nodejs, to use a variable or a function in another file, you have to export them. And we have two type export.

### **1. Use export const**

```
// Export a variable
export const App = () => { ... }

// Import App in another file
import { App } from '...'
```

### **2. Use export default**

```
// Export default
const App = () => { ... }
export default App

// Import App in another file
import App from '...'
```

Follow my example and see your code. You missing export `App` to could use this variable in another file.

So, In your case, you must export `App` to use in `index.js`:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const  increment = () => {
        setCount(count + 1);
    };

    return (
      <div>
          <h2> counter app </h2>
          <button onClick={increment}>Clicked {count} times</button>
      </div>
    );
};
export default App
```

**Remember, you just only have one export default in one file.**

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const  increment = () => {
        setCount(count + 1);
    };

    return (
      <div>
          <h2> counter app </h2>
          <button onClick={increment}>Clicked {count} times</button>
      </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';

class Socket {
  constructor() {
    this.socket = openSocket('http://localhost:8080');
    this.socket.emit("connection", 1000);
  }
}

export default new Socket();


import socketService  from "../../services/socketService";

socketService.socket.on("new-order", (result) => {
  if (result.data) {
    console.log('order page',result.data);
    let x = [...records];
    x.unshift(result.data);
    setRecords(x);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also having same issue with export

1.)when defining with below syntax

```
export const App = ()=>{
}
```

use following for import

```
import { App } from '...';
```

2.)when defining with below syntax

```
 function App = () => {

}
```

export default App
Use following for Import

```
import App  from '...';
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).